# how to prevent showing startup modal for specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal dialog which shown every page load.
But I need to set 10 seconds delay for next modal popup by refh
resh.

it means I refresh page and modal shown, then modal shouldnt shown by refresh for next 10 seconds

this is what I did so far, but couldnt solve it,

```
 var showpopup = "0";
 refreshIntervalId;
 if (refreshIntervalId) {
     refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
         localStorage.setItem("allowShowPopup", "1");
     }, 10000);
 } else {
     showpopup = localStorage.getItem("allowShowPopup");
     if (showpopup == "1") {
         $("#mpopupsLightbox").modal('show');
     }
 }
```

Comment: Let me clarify this, So by the time you refresh the page, the `mpopupsLightbox` should not first show up first until 10 seconds have passed? Or is it the opposite way?

Comment: You need setTimeout not setInterval. While setTimeout triggers once, setInterval repeats infinite per interval until it is cleared.

Comment: @eeya no at first it should show up, then any refresh it shouldnt that in 10 second

Comment: then any refresh it shouldnt that in 10 second > So this means after `mpopupsLightbox` shows up in 10 seconds, it will hide immediately?

Comment: yeah, it shouldnt show up for 10 seconds after its first show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain how i solve my problem. It is [jquery.cookie.js](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) which comes to rescue, I set a cookie which expire after 10 seconds and check if its set popups able to shown if refreshe the page..

Here is the code piece doing this;

```
  if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 1000));
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: date });
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

try this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
   $("#mpopupsLightbox").modal("show");
},10000);
})
```

Comment: This is not my answer, it just trigg pop up 10 sec later, I need it triggered immediately at first refresh than not till 10 seconds passed